# processing jobs from a neverending queue with a fixed number of workers

Tags: concurrency, go

This is doing my head in, I cant figure out how to solve it;

- I want to have a fixed number N of goroutines running in parallell
- From a never-ending queue I will fetch X msg about jobs to process
- I want to let the N goroutines process these X jobs, and as soon as one of the routines have nothing more to do, I want to fetch another X jobs from the neverending queue

The code in the answer below (see url) works brilliantly to process the tasks, but the workers will die once that tasks list is empty, I want them to stay alive and somehow notify the main code that they are out of work so I can fetch more jobs to fill the tasks list with tasks

[How would you define a pool of goroutines to be executed at once in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405023/how-would-you-define-a-pool-of-goroutines-to-be-executed-at-once-in-golang#18406762)

Using user:Jsor example code from below, I try to create a simple program, but I am confused.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

//workChan - read only that delivers work
//requestChan - ??? what is this
func Worker(myid string, workChan <- chan string, requestChan chan<- struct{}) {
    for {
        select {
        case work := <-workChan:
            fmt.Println("Channel: " + myid + " do some work: " + work)
        case requestChan <- struct{}{}:
            //hm? how is the requestChan used?
        }
    }
}

func Logic(){

    workChan := make(chan string)
    requestChan := make(chan struct{})

    //Create the workers
    for i:=1; i < 5; i++ {
        Worker( strconv.Itoa( i), workChan, requestChan)
    }

    //Give the workers some work
    for i:=100; i < 115; i++ {
        workChan<- "workid"+strconv.Itoa( i)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `select` statement is for.

```
func Worker(workChan chan<- Work, requestChan chan<- struct{}) {
    for {
        select {
        case work := <-workChan:
            // Do work
        case requestChan <- struct{}{}:
        }
    }
}
```

This worker will run forever and ever. If work is available, it will pull it from the worker channel. If there's nothing left it will send a request.

Not that since it runs forever and ever, if you want to be able to kill a worker you need to do something else. One possibility is to always check `ok` with workChan and if that channel is closed quit the function. Another option is to use an individual quit channel for each worker.

Comment: Also note that a `case`statement inside a `select` becomes non-blocking, if the corresponding channel is closed.

Comment: thanks! I am still puzzled how it works; What is the requestChan and how is that one used? (see my sample program above)

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the [other solution you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405023/how-would-you-define-a-pool-of-goroutines-to-be-executed-at-once-in-golang#18406762), you just need (first) *not* to close the channel, and just keep feeding items to it.

Then you need to answer the following question: is it absolutely necessary that **(a)** you fetch the next X items from your queue *only* once one of the workers has “nothing more to do” (or, what is the same, once the first X items are either fully processed, or assigned to a worker); or **(b)** is it okay if you keep the second set of X items in memory, and go feeding them to the workers as new work items are needed?

As I understand it, only **(a)** needs the *requestChan* you’re wondering about (see below). For **(b)**, something as simple as the following would suffice:

```golang
# B version

type WorkItem int

const (
  N = 5  // Number of workers
  X = 15 // Number of work items to get from the infinite queue at once
)

func Worker(id int, workChan <-chan WorkItem) {
  for {
    item := <-workChan
    doWork(item)
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d processes item #%v\n", id, item)
  }
}

func Dispatch(workChan chan<- WorkItem) {
  for {
    items := GetNextFromQueue(X)

    for _, item := range items {
      workChan <- item
      fmt.Printf("Dispatched item #%v\n", item)
    }
  }
}

func main() {
  workChan := make(chan WorkItem) // Shared amongst all workers; could make it buffered if GetNextFromQueue() is slow.

  // Start N workers.
  for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
    go Worker(i, workChan)
  }

  // Dispatch items to the workers.
  go Dispatch(workChan)

  time.Sleep(20 * time.Second) // Ensure main(), and our program, finish.
}
```

(I’ve uploaded to the Playground a [full working solution for (b)](http://play.golang.org/p/H8IkGbl07I).)

As for **(a)**, the workers change to say: do work, *or* if there’s no more work, tell the dispatcher to get more via the *reqChan* communication channel. That *“or”* is implemented via *select*. Then, the dispatcher *waits* on *reqChan* before making another call to `GetNextFromQueue()`. It’s more code, but ensures the semantics that you might be interested in. (The previous version is overall simpler, though.)

```golang
# A version

func Worker(id int, workChan <-chan WorkItem, reqChan chan<- int) {
  for {
    select {
    case item := <-workChan:
      doWork(item)
      fmt.Printf("Worker %d processes item #%v\n", id, item)
    case reqChan <- id:
      fmt.Printf("Worker %d thinks they requested more work\n", id)
    }
  }
}

func Dispatch(workChan chan<- WorkItem, reqChan <-chan int) {
  for {
    items := GetNextFromQueue(X)

    for _, item := range items {
      workChan <- item
      fmt.Printf("Dispatched item #%v\n", item)
    }

    id := <-reqChan
    fmt.Printf("Polling the queue in Dispatch() at the request of worker %d\n", id)
  }
}
```

(I’ve also uploaded to the Playground a [full working solution for (a)](http://play.golang.org/p/QrEogt_Xcj).)

Comment: On second thoughts, the second version might be as well be scratched altogether: it adds next to nothing, because select is not guaranteed to succeed in top-bottom order: “If multiple cases can proceed, a uniform pseudo-random choice is made to decide which single communication will execute.” ([link](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)) So as soon as the dispatcher is waiting on `reqChan`, one of the workers may write to it. — Is there something of the simpler version that is not enough for what you want?