# Go Routine for cmd exec but with errorcode

Tags: go, exec

I am a beginner in Go.

I would like to use the code snippet from : [How would you define a pool of goroutines to be executed at once in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405023/how-would-you-define-a-pool-of-goroutines-to-be-executed-at-once-in-golang)
([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406762/448734))

I need to check the error for each cmd executed as in :

```
out, err := exec.Command(cmd,params).Output()
```

But, in the snippet there is no error checking:

```
tasks <- exec.Command("zenity", "--info", "--text='Hello from iteration n."+strconv.Itoa(i)+"'")
```

How can check for errors when the cmd executes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line:

```
tasks <- exec.Command("zenity", "--info", "--text='Hello from iteration n."+strconv.Itoa(i)+"'")
```

is adding a `Cmd` object into the channel, from where it will be pulled later and executed by this code:

```
    for cmd := range tasks {
        cmd.Run()
    }
```

so it is here that you need to check the error code.  Since you suggested you wanted to use `Cmd.Output` instead of `Run`, it would look like this:

```
    for cmd := range tasks {
        out, err := Cmd().Output()
    }
```

You see, `exec.Command` creates and initializes an object, and `.Output` or `.Run` tells that object to do its stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[`exec.Command`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) doesn't execute the command, it creates a `*Cmd` only.

You would check the err in the `go func()`

```
    go func() {
        for cmd := range tasks {
            err := cmd.Run()
            // do the test here
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
```